# extracting specific data from .shp file - python

Tags: python, list

I am a novice python programmer and would love if someone could please help me. 
I am working in python. I have imported a .shp file that contains a heap of data about buildings. I want to extract the data 'RELHMAX' which is the building height maximums - how can I do this ?

this is the data file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BySL_YFrwgAuTTAzeVlacFdFXzA/view?usp=sharing

so far i am thinking that I should be able to use the specific RELHMAX data set by

```
buildingHeight = file[RELHMAX]
print buildingHeight
```

thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried? I would hardly call what you currently have an attempt

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that you're new to programming I suggest the following. Go to google.drive.com and save **south_camden_topo_v2.xlsx** as a google sheet. Now, under the **File** tab, save this as a **csv** file, which is a format that Python processes much more easily that the original **xlsx** format.

I've had a look at the names of the fields in the file. There's none called buildingHeight. However, the following code shows how you can dig out any column you might want. Notice that most of the records seem to lack data for most of the columns.

```
import csv

fieldWanted = 'RELH2'
with open('south_camden_topo_v2.xlsx - south_camden_topo_v2.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    headings = next(reader)
    fieldIndex = headings.index(fieldWanted)
    print (headings)
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
        print (fieldWanted, ':', row[fieldIndex])
        count += 1
        if count > 5 :
            break
```

Notice that this code outputs only the first few records, and the values of RELH2 from these records. Here they are.

```
['FID', 'SCU_ID', 'SCU_CLASSI', 'POLY_SCU', 'THEMES', 'DHM_VOL', 'DHM_MEANH', 'DHM_STDDEV', 'DHM_MINH', 'DHM_MAXH', 'RELH2', 'RELHMAX']
['osgb1000005579280', '52101031610006', '1', 'TRUE', 'Buildings', '547.3700000000', '7.1087012987', '1.2253834286', '0.4000000000', '8.2600000000', '8.6000000000', '11.3000000000']
RELH2 : 8.6000000000
['osgb1000001802821881', '52101037490003', '9', '', 'Buildings', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
RELH2 : 
['osgb1000001802821884', '52101037490002', '9', '', 'Buildings', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
RELH2 : 
['osgb1000005575118', '52101032530003', '3', 'TRUE', 'Buildings', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
RELH2 : 
['osgb1000005574922', '52101052910008', '1', '', 'Buildings', '2449.5140000000', '10.7908105727', '3.3956447143', '0.0000000000', '17.5460000000', '11.6000000000', '19.4000000000']
RELH2 : 11.6000000000
['osgb1000005575392', '52101041010004', '1', '', 'Buildings', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
RELH2 :
```

Comment: thank you so much for you time and help! this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I did find another way that seems to work, although I feel like this isn't the most efficent way

```
all = fileSource

b = copy.copy(fileSource)
b.remove('FID')
b.remove('SCU_CLASSI')
b.remove('POLY_SCU')
b.remove('THEMES')
b.remove('DHM_VOL')
b.remove('DHM_MEANH')
b.remove('DHM_STDDEV')
b.remove('DHM_MINH')
b.remove('DHM_MAXH')
b.remove('RELH2')
b.remove('SCU_ID')
RELHMAX = b

c = copy.copy(fileSource)
c.remove('FID')
c.remove('SCU_CLASSI')
c.remove('POLY_SCU')
c.remove('THEMES')
c.remove('DHM_VOL')
c.remove('DHM_MEANH')
c.remove('DHM_STDDEV')
c.remove('DHM_MINH')
c.remove('DHM_MAXH')
c.remove('RELH2')
c.remove('RELHMAX')
SCU_ID = c
```

but I am now getting an error saying 
"Runtime error (UnboundNameException): name 'copy' is not defined"
and it is no longer running ...